# React Js axios returns empty div before actual data

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, fetch, react-hooks

I'm working on a simple app, where info from JSON should be added on a page. I was able to fetch data from a local JSON file using Axios and display it. The problem is that app renders an empty array(of the selected data) first, and only after that the actual data itself.

local json file:

```
{
    "home": [

{
            "id": "app",
            "management": [
                {
                    "id": "image",
                    "alt": "truck",
                    "img": "./img/assets/img.png",
                    "img2": "./img/assets/img2.png",
                    "img3": "./img/assets/img3.png"
                },
                {
                    "id": "services",
                    "title": "Managementt",
                    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
                     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
                     nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis 
                     aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat 
                     nulla pariatur."
                }
            ]
        }

]
```

My code to fetch data from local JSON is:

```
const [services, setServices] = useState([]);

    const getServices = async () => {
        const response =  await axios.get("./home.json");
        setServices(response.data.home[2].management);
        console.log(response);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getServices();
    }, []);
```

then  it gets displayed using this code:

```
return (
        <>
            <Layout>
                {services.map(({
                        img,
                        img2,
                        img3,
                        id,
                        title,
                        text,
                    }) => (
                        <>
                            <div className={styles.flex}>
                            {id === "image" ? (

                                        <img
                                            id={id}
                                            className={styles.logo}
                                            srcSet={`${img2} 2x,
                                        ${img3} 3x`}
                                            alt={alt}
                                            src={img}
                                        />
                                    ) : null}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {id === "services" ? (
                                        <div className={styles.services} key={id}>
                                            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                                                <h1 className={styles.text}>{title}</h1>
                                            <p>{text}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    ) : null}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    )
                )}


            </Layout>
        </>
```

What happens is before actual image/text gets displayed, the app renders an empty div that can bee seen in console.log(has the same className and parameters as the rendered data, for example, if text's div has a width of 400px, next to the image there is an empty div with 400px width also) and it's messing up all styles. I want to display image and the text as flex(next to each other on the page), but when I use display flex, text's empty array displays first and takes the space near the image, and the actual text gets displayed below the image.

Please see a link to the image how I want to style text and image [flex image-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYe75.png)

I also have to specify the id of the element, otherwise all the images from json file will be rendered.

Any suggestions will be appreciated greatly. Thank you

Comment: useEffect runs after the first render is completed, so you have to check in the render method like if you get the data then render the actual content else you can show loading component while data is getting fetched

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean. I can render actual data, but the problem is that data before data react renders and add as an empty div empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to ckeck before rendering that data exists or not like this

```
if(services.length>0)
{
return (
    <>
        <Layout>
            {services.map(({
                    img,
                    img2,
                    img3,
                    id,
                    title,
                    text,
                }) => (
                    <>
                        <div className={styles.flex}>
                        {id === "image" ? (

                                    <img
                                        id={id}
                                        className={styles.logo}
                                        srcSet={`${img2} 2x,
                                    ${img3} 3x`}
                                        alt={alt}
                                        src={img}
                                    />
                                ) : null}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                {id === "services" ? (
                                    <div className={styles.services} key={id}>
                                        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                                            <h1 className={styles.text}>{title}</h1>
                                        <p>{text}</p>
                                    </div>
                                ) : null}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )
            )}


        </Layout>
    </>
    }
   else{
   return <div> Loading...</div>
   }
```